# Reassign task in SharePoint 2013 using same workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, task-list

I have a requirement to create a workflow with reassign feature.

Example: I have a workflow with 10 tasks and second task is assign to abc group member and that member wants to reassign this task to group xyz member. that workflow will start from second task. 
how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reassign task then you can use Stages in SharePoint 2013.

You can switch stages based on your requirements.

Comment: Stages are used for the next task but i want to reassign the task to from one group to another group.